# Definite integral (in the complex plane?)

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, definite-integrals, contour-integration, multivalued-functions

I want to prove that

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{1+x^b} = \frac{\pi}{b \sin(\pi/b)} \ ,$$

where $b\in (1,\infty)$. I thought about doing it in the complex plane since the integrand is a multivalued function for general $b$, but I cannot isolate the phase shift such that this method works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $\frac{1}{1+x^b}=u$. Then:

$$ I = \frac{1}{b}\int_{0}^{1} u^{-\frac{1}{b}}(1-u)^{\frac{1}{b}-1}\,du=\frac{\Gamma\left(1-\frac{1}{b}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{b}\right)}{b}=\frac{\pi}{b \sin\frac{\pi}{b}} $$

by Euler's [Beta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) and the [reflection formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_formula) for the [$\Gamma$ function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function).

Comment: @Lucian: thanks for the the edit.

Answer (score 2):

I want to give a second solution, which doesn't rely on special functions.

Choosing the branch cut on $(0,\infty)$  and assuming $b>1$ for the moment, we make a substitution $x^b=q, dx=\frac{1}{b}q^{\frac{1}{b}-1}dq$. The resulting integral is

$$
I(b)=\frac{1}{b}\int_0^\infty \frac{q^{1/b-1}dq}{1+q}
$$

Observe that varying the argument of the integrand as $q\rightarrow q\pm i\delta$ we obtain in the limit $\delta\rightarrow 0$
$$
\underbrace{\frac{1}{b}\int_0^\infty \frac{q^{1/b-1}dq}{1+q}}_{\text{above the cut} =I(b)}\quad\text{and}\quad \underbrace{\frac{e^{2\pi i/b}}{b}\int_0^\infty \frac{q^{1/b-1}dq}{1+q}}_{\text{below the cut}= e^{2\pi i/b}I(b)}
$$

Furthermore the integral has a residue at $q=-1$, which is $\text{Res}[q=-1]=\frac{-e^{i\pi/b}}{b}$.

Now choose an keyhole contour and apply residue theorem enclosing the branch cut. The contribution of the origin vanishes and we get
$$
\left[1-e^{2\pi i/b}\right]I(b)=2\pi i\frac{-e^{i\pi/b}}{b}\\
\rightarrow I(b)=\frac{\pi}{b\sin(\pi/b)}
$$

Comment: Why assume $b<1$? Shouldn't it be $b>1$?

Comment: sure, i corrected the typo...

Comment: Thanks for this. Jack D'Aurizio's knowledge of special functions is awe inspiring. But a method without them is less 'black-boxy' for me at least.